# Einliegerwohnung english translation

Tags: translation, word-usage, word-choice, meaning

First let me make a clarification: I live in the ground floor of a house. The owner of the house lives in the upper floor in the same house. We have a common entrance and there is nothing more that I share with them. So I suppose I am living in an *Einliegerwohnung*. If there is another word for the place that I stay please correct me.

Does anyone know what is *Einliegerwohnung* in English. It translates as *Inlay apartment.* But when I search for *inlay apartment* it doesn’t give me any good results.

To make it more clear:

What do I call the kind of apartment where I live? (The context about where I live is mentioned above)

Comment: Maybe `Parterrewohnung` is the word you're looking for.

Comment: Or do you mean `Einliegerwohnung` which translates to `granny flat`?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einliegerwohnung Whether your place is an _Einliegerwohnung_ or not is unrelated to the floor level.

Comment: i have only heard this word. So i had to guess the spelling.

Comment: @chirlu: The floor that i am living doesn't have anything to do with question. i just wanted to let know that I am having not just a room in an apartment but the whole floor in a house.

Comment: Sounds like simple *Wohnung* is it, if you have not only a room but the complete appartement. I'm not aware of any word reflecting, whether the appartement occupies the complete floor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be looking for an *English* term. (It is also somewhat unclear.)

Comment: But I cannot say I am living in a Wohnung. It would imply that I live in a complete home. But I only live in one portion of the home. It can't be a WG either.

Comment: But translations to English are not off topic. Because the tag itself mentions the request can be made for translating to and from German.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan This is surely covered by *Wohnung*, an entire home would translate to *Einfamilienhaus* in classified ads typically abbreviated to EFH. The opposite, *Mehrfamilienhaus*, has several *Wohnungen*.

Comment: So the the place that I stay is not a `Einliegerwohnung` . I could simply say Wohnung?

Comment: @guidot: i have added more details in the questions to make it more clear.

Comment: I find the question difficult to answer, because I don't understand, which aspect you do want to report using that word: *Einliegerwohnung* is a fiscal term of most relevance to the owner; *Eigentums-*, resp *Mietwohnung* would emphasize the aspect of ownership, *Wohnung* in general would emphase the separation aspect; further proposals by Stephie refer mostly to the spaciousness.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is rather appropriate for our sister site http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @em : but in englisg language learners i cant ask the german word that suits best in my situation nor i could give a german word for the translation to english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An **Einliegerwohnung** is a second housing unit in a house that is smaller than the main flat. It is independently accessible, e.g. by a separate entrance or a shared stairwell, but will always be a distinct unit separate from the rest of the house.

It *may* be partly underground or in the basement, it may as well be under the roof. The name signifies the *“importance”* in the house, e.g. often the owners of a house would use the main area and rent out the *Einliegerwohnung* for additional income. It may also be an area used by grown-up children or elderly relatives.

Sometimes the term **Apartment** (note the spelling!) is used as loanword from English, as it has a similar meaning: small unit. But it is not restricted architecturally as *Einliegerwohnung* is, you can build a house with many smallish units which all qualify as *Apartment*.

If a house has many flats, it may have one or multiples per floor, depending on the size of the building. If you *rent* one of them, you are renting eine **(Miet-)Wohnung**. The name doesn’t indicate a size or layout, simply the terms of possession.

Should the house have *one flat per floor*, these may also be called **Etagenwohnung**. This term indicates the architectural property, but no information on the terms - you can both rent or own one.

Note that there is also the (rarely used) term **Appartement** (again: spelling!), which is a French loanword indicating a *larger, superior unit* or a *suite of rooms in a hotel*.

Comment: So i should suppose I live in a _Einliegerwohnung_ or a _Etagenwohnung_

Comment: If you rent a small unit in a larger house: *Einliegerwohnung*. If you have one of "a stack of flats" and want to point that out: *Etagenwohnung*. But in everyday conversation, *Wohnung* would be sufficient in probably 90% of all cases.

Comment: OK. thank you for the clarification. There is no stack of flats in the Wohnung I live. Only 2 floors.

Comment: Interesting that you use *Mietswohnung* where I would say *Mietwohnung.*

Comment: Good answer. What about **self-contained flat/apartment** what I believe may be the closest equivalent to *Einliegerwohnung*.